# KeyboardAvoidingView issue with text input

Tags: react-native, keyboard

I'm using KeyboardAvoidingView to handle keyboard opening inside my app.
I've got an issue with keyboard and bottom margin that you can see in the attachment. The keyboard is covering part of my textinput component.

Here is my component:

```
return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.containerStyle} behavior="padding" enabled>
      <CommentsHeader
        imageUrl={otherParam.imageUrl}
        creationTime={otherParam.creationTime}
        firstName={otherParam.firstName}
        lastName={otherParam.lastName}
      />
      <FlatList
        data={comments.data}
        renderItem={this.renderDetailsItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        style={styles.listStyle}
      />
      <CommentsWrite
        comment={this.state.comment}
        changeText={comment => this.setState({ comment })}
        writeComment={this.writeComment}
      />
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>

);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  listStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    zIndex: 2,
  },

  containerStyle: {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
  },
```

Here is screenshoot of app:

[image]

Comment: have you get solution for this please provide me.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use special prop called keyboardVerticalOffset but when keyboard is closed, there is white space.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView 
        style={styles.containerStyle} 
        behavior="padding" 
        enabled
        keyboardVerticalOffset={90}
        >
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, `behavior="padding"` doesn't give enough padding.

Try `behavior="position"`.

Might want to turn it off for Android though:

```
behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'position' : null}
```

Comment: When i use position my whole screen is moved up 50%

Comment: J.range my screen is showing the same behavior how did you fix it?